# Refresh page when resize using Firefox

Tags: firefox, resize, reload

I have a page with some charts made using chart.js. If I use chrome, the graphs are resized every time I resize the page. However, with Firefox this doesn't work and, to resize with Mozilla i need to press crtl+F5 buttons. I want to do that from the code. I found some solutions in stackoverflow and I choose to use this:

```
<script>
    if (window.onresize){
    window.location.reload(true);
    }
    </script>
```

I write that before closing the  tag. However, with this code, firefox refresh the page continuosly without stop. Someone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1.This is probably what you're looking for

```
    <script>
    var t=0,resizing=false;
    function _reload()
    {
      resizing=false;
      window.location.reload(true);
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
      if(!resizing){
        resizing=true;
        t=setTimeout(_reload, 2000);
      }
    });
  </script>
```

2. before using this, can you make sure that in your chart.js instance you are using the responsive:true parameter? Also you will probably need to use maintainAspectRatio: true parameter as well.

Comment: Yes!!!! It works, Thank you a lot! I spent one week finding the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: The first solution works alone. Was not necessary to use the second point. Thanks!